# Save/load a M5 RWeka caret model fails

Tags: r, r-caret, rweka

I'm coming up with an error after loading a saved M5 implementation of the RWeka package via Caret.

> Error in .jcall(o, "Ljava/lang/Class;", "getClass") :
>
> RcallMethod: attempt to call a method of a NULL object.

To reproduce the error:

```
library(caret); library(RWeka)
data(GermanCredit)

myModel <- train(Duration~Amount, data=GermanCredit, method="M5")
predict(myModel, GermanCredit[1,]) # Works.

save(myModel, file="myModel.rda")
load("myModel.rda")
predict(myModel, GermanCredit[1,]) # Produces the RcallMethod error.
```

[This post](http://one-line-it.blogspot.com/2013/03/r-store-rweka-model-to-file.html) indicates that RWeka objects are references to a Java object, and that object must be serialized in order to save/load properly.

However, I cannot find the right commands to extend this to the Caret package implementation.

Comment: could you provide `MyData` or use a built in dataset so that I can try it out? Maybe `GermanCredit` from `caret`?

Comment: Hack-R, code has been updated to be reproducible.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to take a look at it today

Answer (score 4):

http://one-line-it.blogspot.tw/2013/03/r-store-rweka-model-to-file.html

```
library(RWeka)
j48.model <- J48(formula=class ~ ., data=data)
library(rJava)
.jcache(j48.model$classifier)
save(j48.model, file="j48.model.rda")
```

This may help you.

btw
Are there methods that can make a J48 Rweka classifier into rules?