# How to save a C5.0 model in R and load in another environment

Tags: java, r, model

I have created a model using C50 library in R for classifying emails into various categories. I now want to use the model for classifying new incoming emails in real time using R predict via java. I am not sure how I can save the model from R and load it in another R instance that is used with Java.
Is there any way to save the model to a file and then load the file into R to get the model back for prediction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This post has your answer to how to save a model (which is a java object) into a file, and then later load that file back again:

[Save/load a M5 RWeka caret model fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27991197/save-load-a-m5-rweka-caret-model-fails)

```
library(RWeka) 
j48.model <- J48(formula=class ~ ., data=data) 
library(rJava) 
.jcache(j48.model$classifier) 
save(j48.model, file="j48.model.rda")
```

Answer (score 0):

I used below to save the model from randomForest as I migrated to Radom Forests from Trees. :) . I have also used combine so as to have multiple Random Forests added in same model.

```
mod <- randomForest(as.factor(type)~.-type,data1_rf[,c(5:52)],proximity=FALSE,mtry=5,nodesize=10,ntree=500,importance=FALSE)
mod1 <- randomForest(as.factor(type)~.-type,data2_rf[,c(5:52)],proximity=FALSE,mtry=5,nodesize=10,ntree=500,importance=FALSE)
mod <- combine(mod,mod1)
```

Then just save the final model into a file.

```
save(mod,file="/Rscripts/Models/MULTI23Jul2016.RData")
```

For using it, load the model.

```
mod<-get(load("/Rscripts/Models/MULTI23Jul2016.RData"))
```